# Is there a reason why "gn" in "reigning" is pronounced /n/ while in "regnant" it is pronounced [gn]?

Tags: orthography, pronunciation-vs-spelling, latin, phonology, historical-change

Both *reigning* and *regnant* are related to the same Latin noun, *regnum*.

Why is the ‹gn› spelling pronounced [n] in the first word but [gn] in the second?

Comment: Because *reign* came to us from French, where it is pronounced with a [ɲ] (a consonant that doesn't exist in English), while *regnant* came to us from Latin, where it is pronounced with [gn]?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

My (uneducated) guess would be it has to do with the long vowel sound before the [gn]. It seems to create difficulty to pronounce the [g] sound after a long vowel sound.

Other examples are feign (long), indignity (short), benign (long).

Comment: long vowel or diphtong (double vowel sound, as in 'feign', [ei])

Comment: There is no difficulty in pronouncing a [g] after a long vowel sound: *vagueness*, *league*, *tiger*, *bogart*, *fugue*.

Answer (score 11):

This is probably due to a number of factors, mentioned by commenters.

First, /gn/ is not an allowed syllable coda in English. This prevents *reign*, *malign* from ending in /gn/. However, there is no restriction across syllables; *regnant*, *malignant* have an allowable /g.n/.

Also, the two words followed different paths to get here: *Reign* was borrowed from Norman French, and was spelled <reyne> as early as 1300 indicating the lack of a hard [g] sound.

> OED Etymology: < Anglo-Norman *rengne*, *reng*, *reyn*, Anglo-Norman and Old French *reigne*, Old French *raigne*, *raine*, *reine*, Anglo-Norman and Old French, Middle French *regne*, Middle French *reyne*, French *règne*

*Regnant* appeared later, and was borrowed directly from Latin (though influenced by French), with the hard [g] intact.

> OED Etymology: < classical Latin *regnant-*, *regnāns*, present participle of *regnāre* reign v., partly after Middle French *regnant* (French *régnant*)

Finally, don't fall into the trap of thinking the spelling somehow represents the "true" form of the word that is being strangely mispronounced. In English, spelling is merely a hint about a word's pronunciation. "Reign" was borrowed into English already pronounced /rejn/, and the existence of the letter <g> is a historical artifact.

Answer (score 5):

### On the etymology argument

I'm not convinced that the distinction has any basis in an etymological difference between words borrowed from French or Latin, because it doesn't appear that either language used a hard *g* in these etymons.  Most sources indicate that the pronunciation of *gn* in Latin sounded like *ngn*, or /ŋn/. [This Latin pronunciation guide](http://www.txclassics.org/old/PronunciationGuide.pdf) offers that description:

> ***gn*** had the sound of *ngn* as in English wing nut: *magnus*, *benignus*, *ignāvus*

[John Well's Phonetic Blog](http://phonetic-blog.blogspot.com/2009/06/more-about-nasals-palatal-and-velar.html) offers a similar account:

> Most English-speaking classicists, I think, say *ɡn* in Latin words such as *agnus*, *dignus*, *regnum*. But choral singers and Catholics tend to be influenced by Italian and say *nj* [or /ɲ/]. In classical Latin *gn* appears to have stood for neither *ɡn* nor *ɲ*, but rather for *ŋn*, thus *aŋnus*, *diŋnus*, *reŋnũ* (Allen, Vox Latina, CUP 1965).

The point here is that if Latin speech pronounced "gn" in words like "regnum" as "*ngn*" /ŋn/, the hard *g* in English could not have come from either Latin or French.  This is why I shy away from pinning the use of hard *g* on differences in etymology between *reign* and *regnant*.

**Other words of French origin**

If the distinction really had roots in Latin vs. French etymology, we would be hard-pressed to explain the myriad other instances that follow the pattern wherein the *g* is dropped only in the last syllable of a word, regardless of whether the words derive from French or Latin.

Consider some other words where the hard *g* is pronounced in English but not in derivative French. [All etymology notes from OED]

- **dignity**: Old French *digneté*, French *dignité*
- **ignore**: French *ignorer*, or Latin *ignōrāre* not to know
- **pregnant**: French *pregnant*; Latin *praegnant-*, *praegnāns*.
- **signature**:  French *signature*; Latin *signātūra*.

Compare this etymology of "signature" with the etymology of "sign."

- **sign**:  French seigne; Latin signum

Whether the words derive from Latin or French, the tendency in English is to pronounce the hard *g* when the digraph is neither at the beginning nor the end of the word.

### Signs of shift

It makes sense that the *g* remains silent in a first or final syllable simply because English pronunciation has no way to retain the hard *g* otherwise. The appearance of the hard *g* in the middle of a word could be explained as either a drift from the Latin *velar nasal* /ŋ/ (think "ng") or the French *palatal nasal* /ɲ/ (think Spanish ñ), or as a result of phonetic pronunciation of the spellings.

A possible clue to the process words underwent attaining the hard g can be found in old spellings of some of these words of French origin, which retain the velar nasal /ŋ/ we would expect in Latin pronunciation.

- **Pregnant** has late Middle English  *pre**ng**navnt*, *pri**ng**nant*
- **Dignity** has Middle English *dy**ng**nete*, *di**ng**nete*

These early spellings with the presence of *ng* suggest that the *gn* pronunciation might have used the Latin pronunciation /ŋn/ earlier than the hard *g*, supporting the argument that the hard *g* developed within English.

### *Poignant* and *vignette*

Some words of French origin have retained the silent "g," still treating *gn* as /ɲ/, at least per OED:

- **Poignant**: /ˈpɔɪn(j)ənt/
- **Vignette**: /vɪnˈjɛt/

I think this is another clue that the hard *g* developed within English.  While the OED describes *poignant* as retaining a palatal nasal sound, it *is* sometimes pronounced (mistakenly?) with a hard *g*, as [a questioner observed on this site](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/164991/why-is-poignant-pronounced-%CB%88p%C9%94%C9%AA%C9%B2%C9%99nt).  In that sense, the drift can almost be seen in progress.  At the least, the fact that its pronunciation is confusing to English speakers or learners seems indicative of the *norm* that English expects a hard *g* from *gn* in the middle of a word.

**Vignette**, which entered the English language as recently as the 18th century, retains the French pronunciation probably because it was adopted into English more recently than the other words cited.

Comment: I rather wonder whether you've not mis-written /ŋ/ for /ɲ/ in most places here; think English *onion, canyon*. In modern French and Italian, the ‹gn› digraph is [the **palatal nasal** /ɲ/](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Palatal_nasal) in most positions: French *oignon, signature, beignet, poignant, rossignol*; Italian *ogni, cognoscente, signora, bisogna*.  This is the same sound represented by: the Spanish letter ‹ñ› of *niño, cañón*; the Portuguese and Occitan digraph ‹nh› of *piranha, caipirinha*; and the Catalan digraph ‹ny› of *Catalunya*. In Italian it geminates to [ɲn] **not** to [ŋn].

Comment: @tchrist Note the line:  *In classical Latin gn appears to have stood for neither ɡn nor ɲ, but rather for ŋn*.  The argument is that in Latin, it was "ngn", like "mangnum" for "magnum."  Hence: *It's possible the words that did not develop a hard g also underwent the same shift in the opposite direction, from /ŋ/ to /n/.*  In the first paragraph I'm describing the Latin pronunciation /ŋn/ ( as "in between" the palatal nasal and the hard "g."  Whether or not that description is a good description is a valid question.

Comment: But /ŋ/ is not the palatal nasal!!!  It's the [**velar nasal**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Velar_nasal) of *conquer, sink, fang*. The palatal nasal is /ɲ/. You keep saying palatal nasal and writing velar nasal; I know no evidence that this was ever velar rather than palatal. Think *senior* versus *sinker*: those are very different sounds, the first palatal and the second velar. The velar one is much farther back. The palatal one is with the front of your tongue; the velar one with the back.

Comment: @tchrist Maybe I should never have used the words *velar nasal* or *palatal nasal* while also using the symbolic pronunciation because it seems to be causing a misunderstanding.  The two links I provided first in the answer both suggest there was a velar rather than palatal, and you can hear it in this [pronunciation of "magnum"](https://www.howtopronounce.com/latin/magnum/).  So you can disagree with my answer, but I don't think we're on the same page regarding whether I've misused terms, unless I'm still missing something.

Comment: I've listened to your sample: that's the palatal  /ɲ/ not the velar /ŋ/. As in French *mignonette* not as in English *singer* or even *finger*. Wells is writing /nj/ to mean  /ɲ/, and I am no one to argue with him; I'm sure he's right that we tend to use the Italianized version these days.

Comment: @tchrist The quote from my first link is brief: "gn had the sound of ngn as in English wing nut: magnus, benignus, ignāvus" In that example would you acknowledge that it is a description of the velar /ŋ/ ?  And from the second source: "Latin gn appears to have stood for neither ɡn nor ɲ, but rather for ŋn" <--- explicitly saying "not the palatal, the velar."  Do you dispute the sources, or how I'm presenting them?

Comment: @tchrist I’m not sure if the link you listened to two years ago had the same recording as it does now, but the current one very clearly has a velar /ŋ/, and that is indeed also the commonly accepted allophonic pronunciation of /g/ before /n/ in Classical Latin. What this answer misses is that this was not generally known in the 13th–17th centuries when many words were (re-)borrowed from Latin. Most of those (re-)borrowings were pronounced in a way that intended to emulate Latin, but neither truly English nor truly Latin. So I don’t think the etymology can be discounted outright.