# What is the word for "the way a word sounds to your ear"?

Tags: meaning, word-choice, single-word-requests, sounds

I do not mean "Phonaesthetics" or euphony or cacophony which carry a value judgement. Words have an audio 'pattern', mostly unique and different from other words. This is the unique audio "finger-print" of the word, which does not carry a un/pleasant connotation - it is simply the sound of a (particular word) being spoken. I am looking for the definition or term for the sound of word/s. Does such a term exist? I used to think it was "nomenclature".

Comment: "sound of the word"

Comment: Alas, I really hoped you **were** asking about [phonaesthetics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phonaesthetics)! :)  I don’t imagine you’re looking for the sort of acoustic *sonogram* that linguists use in certain sorts of speech analysis tasks?

Comment: The *phonetics* of a word would be the meaningful sounds ([phonemes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phoneme_%28phonetics%29)) of which a word is composed. A phoneme is composed of one or more *phones* (elements of physical sound regardless of meaning).

Comment: Did you mean how a word sounds to the individual person? Or hearing your own voice?

Answer (score 3):

Most dictionaries will only give equivalents to the following two definitions...

> [**phonology**](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/phonology?q=phonology)
>    1:*The system of contrastive relationships among the speech sounds that constitute the fundamental components of a language.*
>    2:*The study of phonological relationships within a language or between different languages.*

But [here are almost 3000 written instances of...](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22the%20wreck%20lies%20in%22%20%22feet%20of%20water%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#q=%22the%20phonology%20of%20the%20word%22&tbm=bks)

> *the **phonology** of the word [some word being discussed]...*

I think that's enough to establish that it's a valid "neutral" term to use in this way.

Comment: _Phonology_ specifically **does** mean "the way words in a language sound to a native speaker". As opposed to _phonetics_, which is about the physiological production of sounds.

Answer (score 3):

It is called a **[signifier](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/signifier)**.

> **1** *Linguistics* A linguistic unit or pattern, such as a succession of speech sounds, written symbols, or gestures, that conveys meaning; a linguistic sign.
>
> > The signifier of the concept "tree" is, in English, the string of speech sounds (t), (r), and (ē); in German, (b), (ou), and (m).
>
> **2** the phonological or orthographic sound or appearance of a word that can be used to describe or identify something

According to Swiss linguist [Ferdinand de Saussure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Course_in_General_Linguistics):

> The sign (signe) is described as a "double entity", made up of the **signifier, or sound image** (signifiant), and the signified, or concept (signifié).
>
> The sound image is a psychological, not a material concept, belonging to the system. Both components of the linguistic sign are inseparable.

Comment: That reminds me that [*signifié* and *significant* are among the loan-words that the OED assigns the **ɲ** phoneme to](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/165035).

Comment: @tchrist: Nice reference! Now we know more about the original signifiers.

Answer (score 2):

The characteristic sound associated with a word when it is spoken correctly is its **pronunciation** .

Answer (score 0):

**Vocable**: [A word considered only as a sequence of sounds or letters rather than as a unit of meaning.](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Vocable)

**Phthongal**: [Of or pertaining to sound; vocal; sonant.](http://www.finedictionary.com/Phthongal.html)

Answer (score 0):

Are you talking about the absolute simplest form of words?

[Morpheme](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Morpheme): A morphological unit of a language that cannot be further divided (e.g., in, come, -ing, forming *incoming*).

This isn't the sound of words, but the sounds that *make up* words.

The word for *sounds of a word* is: **[Phonology](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phonology)** (see @FumbleFingers' answer) which is the *branch of linguistics concerned with the systematic organization of sounds in languages*.

An interesting field that delves into this is [Morphophonology](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Morphophonology) as it *is a branch of linguistics which studies the interaction between [morphological](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Morphology_%28linguistics%29) and [phonological](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phonology) or [phonetic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phonetic) processes*.