# Why are "malign" and "malignant" pronounced differently?

Tags: pronunciation, pronunciation-vs-spelling, morphology, consonants

Why are *malign* and *malignant* pronounced differently?  What is the rule that separates that pattern from, say, *sign* and *signage*?

Comment: Related: [Is there a reason why 'gn' in 'reigning' is pronounced /n/ while in 'regnant' it is pronounced /gn/?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/150937)

Comment: The rule is the same for *sign* and *significant*.

Comment: They all work this way: *assign/assignation, benign/benignant, consign/consignation, design/designation, indign/indignant, obsign/obsignation, resign/resignation,  sign/signify*.

Comment: @tchrist: What do you mean? "They all work this way" is too vague to be useful. Geoff points out that at least two patterns exist for words ending in "ign" and related words with suffixes: *signage* is not pronounced /sɪgnɪdʒ/.  (There are actually even more possible patterns if we expand things a bit to look at other words spelled with "-ign-": *[poignant](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/164991/why-is-poignant-pronounced-ˈpɔɪɲənt)* in modern English is usually pronounced /poɪnjənt/, not /poɪgnənt/ or /poɪnənt/.)

Comment: @sumelic English cannot have /ɲ/ in the syllable coda, so that sound always reduces to /n/ there, even when the source language had /ɲ/—which is the phoneme represented by the ‹gn› digraph in French whence most of these derive (also in Italian). Hence *feign, design, oppugn, impugn, impregn, campaign, arraign,* &c. Add a couple more syllables and this shows up as /g.n/ *designation, oppugnation, impugnation, impregnation* &c; note also *Cologne, Bologna*. In *poignant* /ˈpoɪ.ɲənt/ it's intervocalic and recent enough to retain the original  /ɲ/ pronunciation, like *lasagne* <IT, *canyon* <ES.

Comment: @sumelic We also hear the same phonological pattern with *phlegm/phlegmatic, diaphragm/diaphragmatic, hypodigm/hypodigmatical, polystigm/polystigmatic, tristigm/tristigmatic*. And there's no /g/ is *syntagm* either.

Answer (score 0):

malign and malignant may look and sound similar but they are two very different words.
malign should be a verb- to "malign" someone, to speak ill-of, to paint them in an unflattering light, usually through "malicious" lies. Malicious being derived from malign- a malicious act.

Malignant sounds like a noun- a malignant tumor, something usually meaning cancerous, or the most horrible, worst form of a disease. A terrible person or presence- oh he's malignant and ruins everything he touches.

Comment: This does not appear to answer the question.

Comment: "malignant" is an adjective, and this sounds like a non-answer.

Comment: Malign is also an adjective, not just a verb.